# Locking the measuring tool at a certain depth relative to the view

Tags: modeling

If you have a situation like this...
[image]

Is there a way to lock the measuring tool in the the view point's z dimension?
That is so it reads like 4.3', instead of that 7.9' dimension.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to uncheck the snap button:

[image]

Comment: I'd like to still snap to it though, to get the exact measurement (without the z depth, that is)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but:

This method uses the Add Mesh: Extra Objects addon that comes with Blender. It has to be activated.

I have located the cubes approximately as shown in the question:

[image]

In Front Orthographic view and Edit mode, select the vertex at the bottom front of the lower cube and snap the 3D cursor to it:

[image]

In Object mode add a single vertex:

[image]

In Front Orthographic view and Edit mode, with vertex snapping turned on, press E, then Shift->Y and snap the vertex to the corner of the upper cube:

[image]

Use the Measure tool as you wanted:

[image]

This is what it has done:

[image]